# How can change config file?

Tags: c#, csv, multilingual

I have .csv language files and my program changes the language by writing it in the xml config file . I created a combobox in my form and ı added my languages. My problem is when ı choose En for example the string in config to be changed to english and restart the program.

setting name="Language" serializeAs="String"
                value Turkish

Comment: Can you please share us the code? Then will look into it. Without code how will I know what you are doing.

Comment: This is code in the config  <setting name="Language" serializeAs="String">
                <value>Turkish</value>
            </setting> 
The program doesnt have an option for language changes ı translated them inside the csv file and added a combobox of item in fr and en when ı choose the items . I want the code in config turkish to be replaced as english .

Comment: [global::System.Configuration.ApplicationScopedSettingAttribute()]
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("Turkish")]
        public string Language {
            get {
                return ((string)(this["Language"]));
            }
        }
         This is how it changes

Comment: this really depends on what settings system you are using. You might want to explain a bit more about how these settings are declared.

Comment: Still it's not clear what you want from us. Can you please elaborate with your code. So looked into the same.

Comment: I am creating a toolbox for multilanguage setting in UI , if the user selects en the string in the config file should be replaced with english , restart and texts change to english. The translation part is already implemented what ı need to do is link the combobox selection with changing of the config file string.

Comment: You should not set settings in your app.config, web.config or project.json for security reasons. If you deploy your app, those files are most likely in a folder where the user doesn't have write access. For desktop apps you have user settings out of the box that you can leverage. For web apps there are well documented means to use the Options pattern that can support what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

You can load and change your application's Web.config using System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration. But that will cause your application to restarts every time you make any changes and save.

You can implement the same features using another xml file by the following steps

```
# Create an xml file in your project directory.
# Put your configuration settings
# Create a reader class that will retrieve values based on node/key/attributes
# Create a writer class that will store your selected language settings
```